# How do I determine what profile a given Nuget Package supports?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, portable-class-library

Went to add a nuget package to my project in Visual Studio 2017. Waited 5 minutes for the Download and install and get.

> Could not install package 'Foo.Bar 1.0'. You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7'

so do a bit of config restrict my profile down try again and get

> Could not install package 'Foo.Bar 1.0'. You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.6,Profile=Profile44'

So how do I tell what magic numbers a Given Nuget supports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I determine what profile a given Nuget Package supports?

The .NETPortable identifier is used for portable libraries. Each portable library may run on a number of different platforms, indicated by a profile named Profile_N_.

The .NETPortable identifier requires a profile. The profiles are listed below:

https://portablelibraryprofiles.stephencleary.com/

So we could to know the profile numbers a given NuGet supports according to the **NuGet Target** in that list.

**Update for Comment:**

> How do I determine what "NuGet Target" a given nuget package supports?

When we given a nuget package, we can open it with [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/downloads/get/clickOnce/NuGetPackageExplorer.application), like Newtonsoft.Json:

[image]

We could to know the nuget target are "`portable-net40+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81`" and "`portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81`", then check that profile list, we could to know the profile should be `Profile259` and `Profile328`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...but though I think this might be a step closer the basic question remains. How do I determine what "NuGet Target" a given nuget package supports?

Comment: @David, not sure I understand you correct. I have updated my answer with   some detailed info, you can check if it help you.

Comment: Thanks Leo that was it. I didn't know if there was an easier way in the IDE besides downloading the package and looking at its contents and really didnt know what I was looking for in the contents to make the decision.